# Authenticating Apache HTTPd against Active Directory

Tags: apache-2.2, active-directory, ldap, authentication

We're using Apache 2.2.12 to authenticate against one Active Directory domain using a .htaccess configuration file.

Our current configuration is:

```
AuthBasicProvider ldap
AuthType Basic
AuthName "AD LDAP Test"
AuthLDAPURL "ldap://192.168.0.10:389/OU=Users,DC=test,DC=site?sAMAccountName?sub"
AuthzLDAPAuthoritative On
AuthLDAPBindDN "administrator@test.site"
AuthLDAPBindPassword "Password"
require ldap-group CN=Sysadmins,OU=Users,DC=test,DC=site
```

We're encountering issues with authentication of users during access and authentication of the website.

```
[Sun Mar 16 13:26:25 2014] [warn] [client 192.168.0.10] [6740] auth_ldap authenticate: user rene authentication failed; URI / [ldap_search_ext_s() for user failed][No such object]
[Sun Mar 16 13:26:25 2014] [error] [client 192.168.0.10] user rene not found: /
```

The authentication of the AuthLDAPBindDN is working because if I change the password I receive

```
[Sun Mar 16 13:20:37 2014] [warn] [client 192.168.0.10] [6360] auth_ldap authenticate: user rene authentication failed; URI / [LDAP: ldap_simple_bind_s() failed][Invalid credentials]
[Sun Mar 16 13:20:37 2014] [error] [client 192.168.0.10] user rene: authentication failure for "/": Password Mismatch
```

during the authentication.

I verified the authentication with

```
ldapsearch -x -h 192.168.0.10 -LLL -b dc=test,dc=tc -D cn=rene,cn=Users,dc=test,dc=site -W "(cn=rene)" cn sAMAccountName
```

successful.

How can I configure Apache to correctly authenticate against the Active Directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your test, you have:

```
cn=rene,cn=Users,dc=test,dc=site
```

In your configuration you have:

```
OU=Users,DC=test,DC=site
```

So... is Users a OU or a cn? Seems like this is your problem.

Comment: You are right. "Users" is a Active Directory build-in container and not a OU. To access it I have to use the CN. Thanks!